# Selecionar elemento com base no atributo data-id

Tags: javascript, html

Come eu faço para pegar o `id` no JavaScript que, no HTML, está `data-id="2"` ?

```
<ul>
  <li data-id="1" id="e1">Elemento 1</li>
  <li data-id="2" id="e2">Elemento 2</li>
  <li data-id="3" id="e3">Elemento 3</li>
</ul>
```

Por exemplo, para o HTML acima, gostaria de receber o id `e2`, visto que esse é o que possui `data-id="2"`.

Comment: Porquê o negativo? Todo mundo já deve nascer sabendo como faz isso?

Comment: TheCoder, poderia confirmar se você precisa buscar o elemento que possui `data-id=2` ou o que você quer é o valor 2?

Comment: quero ir buscar se algum elemento possui data-id=2

Comment: Poderia pegar pelo `id` direto, não?

Comment: O id é so de exemplo. Eu tou a criar uma API em que o outro programador pode criar o seu próprio botão, basta so colocar este atributo para ele funcionar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em puro javascript pode ser asssim:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[data-id='2']")
```

Como irá retornar um array de elementos, precisa verificar se retornou algum, e pegar o primeiro elemento, em seguida o id:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[data-id='2']")[0].id
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, eu uso js puro!

Answer (score 4):

Pode usar o [`document.QuerySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) com o seletor **`data-id='2'`**.

Esta função irá retornar **um elemento** que atenda ao seletor, caso não exista nenhum elemento que atenda à condição será retornado `null`.

```js
var elemento = document.querySelector("[data-id='2']");
console.log(`id: ${elemento.id} \ndata-id: ${elemento.dataset.id}`);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-id="1" id="e1">Elemento 1</li>
  <li data-id="2" id="e2">Elemento 2</li>
  <li data-id="3" id="e3">Elemento 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!